# Adding custom header in custom membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, http-headers, membership-provider

I have an MVC 3 app I am trying to create some custom authentication for. Right now I have a custom (RequiresToken) attribute on all locked-down controllers that then redirects back to the login page. When you login I have a custom membership provider calling a rest svc of mine that returns an oauth token (with refresh). I would like to then add the Authorization header in the membership provider but get the error:

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.

I am just doing an add after I verify the result is confirmed.

```
        if (result)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", token.access_token);
        }
```

Is this because I have the MembershipProvider in another assembly? I know I am missing something simple but having trouble deciphering it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get this error if you're using the Visual Studio Web Server (Cassini).  It is the 'unsupported platform' referenced in your error message.  You should be able to switch over to a local install of IIS to alleviate this issue.